# Let $a, b$, and $c$ be unit vectors such that $a\cdot b=1/3 , b\cdot c=1/7$ and $a\cdot c=1/10$. Find $(a+b+c)\cdot (a−b)$

Tags: vectors

So from this, I managed to find out the magnitude of $a,b,$ and $c$ respectively, finding out my previous parts:

$3a\cdot 7b = 3$

$a\cdot (b−c) = 7/30$

But I can't seem to find $(a+b+c)\cdot(a−b)$ :/ Any clues?

Comment: Seems you don't actually need to know $a\cdot b$

Comment: You’re given the magnitudes of the vectors: “Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be _unit vectors_...”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clues:**

Use properties of dot product such as $(d+e)\cdot f=d\cdot f+ e\cdot f,$

$ g\cdot h=h\cdot g$, and if $i$ is a unit vector then $i\cdot i=1$.

Comment: I expanded and found the following:
a.a + b.b +a.c -b.c 
1+1 +a.c-b.c
Thanks :)

Comment: I get $a\cdot a - a \cdot b + b\cdot a - b\cdot b + c\cdot a - c\cdot b=1-1+c\cdot a - c\cdot b=a\cdot c - b\cdot c$